# Rails 3.2.18: How does an ActiveRecord turn into a NilClass from one statement to the next?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm working on a Rails 3.2.18 application that uses an `ActiveRecord` called `Address`. This snippet of code works like you'd expect:

```
<% addresses = Address.where(user_id: user.id) %>
<% addresses.each do |address| %>
<td><%= address.address1 %><br /><%= address.city %>, <%= address.state %> <%= address.zip %></td>
<% end %>
```

It selects one `Address` and returns the information. However, I don't want to loop through a single item to get the information, and I think I should be able to call the `.first` method on my `Address` objects. But here's what happens when I try:

```
<% a = addresses.first %>
<%= debug(a) %>
<!-- prints out a YAML dump of the attributes of the Address object -->
<%= a.nil? %>
<!-- prints "false" -->
<%= a.class %>
<!-- prints "Address" -->
```

All well and good, but as soon as I add this statement:

```
<%= a.city %>
```

Rails throws an error saying `undefined method 'city' for nil:NilClass`.

How does `a` go from being an `Address` to a `NilClass` from one statement to the next? And how can I extract my address information from my `Address` `ActiveRecord` without having to do the `.each` block?

EDIT

Here are the first few lines of the stack trace generated when this exception is thrown:

```
   Showing /home/creede/rails/marches2-dev/app/views/stations/index.html.erb where line #49 raised:

 undefined method `city' for nil:NilClass

   Extracted source (around line #49):

 46:     <%= debug(a) %>
 47:     <%= a.nil? %>
 48:     <%= a.class %>
 49:     <%= a.city %>
 50:     <% addresses.each do |address| %>
 51:     <td><%= address.address1 %><br /><%= address.city %>, <%= address.state %> <%= address.zip %></td>
 52:     <% end %>

   Rails.root: /home/creede/rails/marches2-dev

   Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

 app/views/stations/index.html.erb:49:in `block in _app_views_stations_index_html_erb___174412722496690062_69855565287900'
 app/views/stations/index.html.erb:29:in `each'
 app/views/stations/index.html.erb:29:in `_app_views_stations_index_html_erb___174412722496690062_69855565287900'
 app/controllers/stations_controller.rb:7:in `index'

 actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
 activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:125:in `instrument'
 actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
 actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:47:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
 actionpack (3.2.18) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
 activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
 activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
 activesupport (3.2.18) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
```

Comment: where is `city` defined? Where are you adding that line of code `a.city`?

Comment: also, it does not 'select one address' - it returns you an ActiveRecord::Relation of all addresses that have the user_id: `user.id`. That's why you can call `first` on it - if it was a single Address object, you could not.

Comment: (1) 'City' is a field in the "addresses" table in my db, associated with the Address ActiveRecord. (2) I'm adding "a.city" right after "a.class", but it doesn't really matter - adding it anywhere after `a` is defined causes the error. (3) There's only one row in the table that has the specified `user_id`, but I can still iterate over it and, apparently, call `first` on it.

Comment: A relation can have any number of elements - zero, one, or more than one - and it will always be enumerable.

Comment: can you add the entire backtrace of the error to the question?

Comment: Do you have it listed in attr_accesible in your model ?

Comment: @GhostBuster yes, the model was generated automatically through `rails generate scaffold` and lists all the fields in the DB table.

Comment: @sevenseacat I'll add the first few lines of the stack trace to the question. If you want to see the full thing, it's at http://pastebin.com/aQgEZ1eU; it's 17K long.